# 64 bit file system on Unix

Tags: filesystems

Is the file structure on a 64 bit OS different than the structure on the same OS that is 32 bit? I know this might be dependent on the OS, but I saw a post that the files were different.

As a practical example, can I copy a text or binary file from a 64 bit system to a 32 bit system with no issues? I assume this is the case as this is how things work on Windows.

Answer (score 5):

There are no common filesystems that I am aware of that have any dependency on a specific processor architecture.  EXT(2,3,4) are the same filesystem on an ARM, x86, x64, ia64, ppc, mips, or any other CPU.

The files stored on the filesystem will be available on any system that can mount the filesystem.

Of course any executable content (programs) will only run on an appropriate architecture.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ZFS which is 128 bit with a 32 bit OS. There is no relationship between OSes and file systems respective sizes.